# Как добавить символы в тег через jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть html тег, c помощью jQuery, необходимо добавить символы в конец тега, подскажите как реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Взять символы из тега через селектор.html() (https://api.jquery.com/html/) или text (https://api.jquery.com/text/) - что больше подходит. И положить в переменную
- К этой переменной добавить через конатенацию ещё любые символы, какие нужны
- Дальше сделать так: селектор.html(ТУТ_ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ_С_ДОБАВОЧНЫМИ СИМВОЛАМИ)  или  селектор.text(ТУТ_ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ_С_ДОБАВОЧНЫМИ СИМВОЛАМИ) в зависимости от того, что требуется

Comment: Не совсем понял, как дописать добавочные символы, `var base = $(".base").html(); $('.base').html(); ` я создал переменную, а вот добавочные символы не вводятся так, как  надо, чтобы они были в одной строке с переменной, помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: где в вашем коде вот такая строчка `селектор.html(ТУТ_ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ_С_ДОБАВОЧНЫМИ СИМВОЛАМИ)` ?  а где  к переменной `base` конкатенируются нужные символы? Т.е. по факту вы сделали только 1-ый пункт из трёх